# Use the output of ui.Select widget as an argument for filtering an image collection (Earh Engine code editor)

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, widget, dynamic-world

I am trying to filter.Bound an image collection (in this example Dynamic World) with the 1st level administrative boundaries of Nigeria (I am using here GAUL by FAO) by  using the ui.Select widget.
The idea is to select the required Nigeria State and get the resulting image clipped accordingly.
Finally I want to display the resulting layer on the map canvas.

However, I get the following error: "LULC_before: Layer error: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Below goes the code I am trying (apologies if it is a bit verbose)  and the link to the EE code editor script.

```
var table = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level1')

var Abia = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Abia'));
var Adamawa = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Adamawa'));
var Akwa_Ibom = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Akwa Ibom'));
var Anambra = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Anambra'));
var Bauchi = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Bauchi'));
var Bayelsa = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Bayelsa'));
var Benue = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Benue'));
var Borno = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Borno'));
var Cross_River = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Cross River'));
var Delta = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Delta'));
var Ebonyi = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Ebonyi'));
var Edo = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Edo'));
var Ekiti = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Ekiti'));
var Enugu = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Enugu'));
var FCT = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Federal Capital Territory'));
var Gombe = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Gombe'));
var Imo = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Imo'));
var Jigawa = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Jigawa'));
var Kaduna = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Kaduna'));
var Kano = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Kano'));
var Katsina = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Katsina'));
var Kebbi = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Kebbi'));
var Kogi = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Kogi'));
var Kwara = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Kwara'));
var Lagos = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Lagos'));
var Nassarawa = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Nassarawa'));
var Niger = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Niger'));
var Ogun = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Ogun'));
var Ondo = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Ondo'));
var Osun = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Osun'));
var Oyo = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Oyo'));
var Plateau = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Plateau'));
var Rivers = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Rivers'));
var Sokoto = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Sokoto'));
var Taraba = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Taraba'));
var Water_body = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Water body'));
var Yobe = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Yobe'));
var Zamfara = 
    table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', 'Zamfara'));


var places = {
  Abia: [Abia],
  Adamawa: [Adamawa],
  Akwa_Ibom: [Akwa_Ibom],
  Anambra: [Anambra],
  Bauchi: [Bauchi],
  Bayelsa: [Bayelsa],
  Benue: [Benue],
  Borno: [Borno],
  Cross_River: [Cross_River],
  Delta: [Delta],
  Ebonyi: [Ebonyi],
  Edo: [Edo],
  Ekiti: [Ekiti],
  Enugu: [Enugu],
  FCT: [FCT],
  Gombe: [Gombe],
  Imo: [Imo],
  Jigawa: [Jigawa],
  Kaduna: [Kaduna],
  Kano: [Kano],
  Katsina: [Katsina],
  Kebbi: [Kebbi],
  Kogi: [Kogi],
  Kwara: [Kwara],
  Lagos: [Lagos],
  Nassarawa: [Nassarawa],
  Niger: [Niger],
  Ogun: [Ogun],
  Ondo: [Ondo],
  Osun: [Osun],
  Oyo: [Oyo],
  Plateau: [Plateau],
  Rivers: [Rivers],
  Sokoto: [Sokoto],
  Taraba: [Taraba],
  Water_body: [Water_body],
  Yobe: [Yobe],
  Zamfara: [Zamfara]
};

var select = ui.Select({
  items: Object.keys(places),
  onChange: function(key) {
    Map.centerObject(places[key][0], places[key][1]);
var geometry = ee.FeatureCollection(table)
  .filter(select)
  .geometry();



var dw_before_coll = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1')
     .filterDate('2019-07-01', '2019-10-31')
     .filterBounds(geometry);
     
var dwVisParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 8,
  palette: ['#DFC35A', '#DFC35A', '#DFC35A', '#DFC35A',
    '#C4281B', '#DFC35A', '#DFC35A', '#DFC35A', '#DFC35A']
};

     

     
var dw_before = dw_before_coll.mosaic().clip(geometry);

var class_before = dw_before.select('label');



Map.addLayer(class_before,dwVisParams,'LULC_before');

  }
    
  });
 
select.setPlaceholder('Choose a State');
print(select);
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9f33112efdc548a435170ea658d0c713

Answer (score 0):

You're running too many filters unnecessarily. You can use an array to store the names of the locations and use these locations as items in a `ui.Select` widget.

```js
var table = ee.FeatureCollection('FAO/GAUL/2015/level1');

var dw = ee.ImageCollection('GOOGLE/DYNAMICWORLD/V1').filterDate('2019-07-01', '2019-10-31');

var visParams = {
  min: 0,
  max: 8,
  palette: [
    '#DFC35A', '#DFC35A', '#DFC35A', 
    '#DFC35A', '#C4281B', '#DFC35A',
    '#DFC35A', '#DFC35A', '#DFC35A',
  ],
};

var layer = ui.Map.Layer();
layer.setVisParams(visParams);

Map.layers().add(layer);

var locs = [
  'Abia',
  'Adamawa',
  'Akwa Ibom',
  ...
]
```

The `ui.Select` widget callback function will use the name of the chosen location as an argument for the `FeatureCollection` filter.

```js
var select = ui.Select({
  items: locs,
  onChange: function (loc) {
    var location = table.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM1_NAME', loc)).geometry();
    Map.centerObject(location);

    var dwFiltered = dw.filterBounds(location);

    var mosaic = dwFiltered.select('label').mosaic().clip(location);
    layer.setEeObject(mosaic);
  },
});

print(select);
```

After filtering the `FeatureCollection`, the geometry of the result is extracted.

After extracting the geometry of the chosen location, the function uses this geometry to filter the collection of images, generate the mosaic, and clip it out according to the limits of the geometry.

Finally, the function updates the layer `eeObject` with the `mosaic`.

https://code.earthengine.google.com/8e9bf4ae36ba197a5891c404288484e9

Comment: It works in terms of filtering but the output image does not cover the full area, only bits are displayed

Comment: In the code provided in my answer, all the images acquired within the time interval you specified are used to create the mosaic. If the mosaic doesn't fully cover the area of interest, it could be due to a lack of images or the fact that the clouds and cloud shadows are masked in this collection. Visit this link for more information about the collection: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/GOOGLE_DYNAMICWORLD_V1#description